# How to update from laravel4 beta to laravel4 stable release

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm a laravel newb, so this might be a question most of you find stupid, but I haven't found a straight answer to this one even after several hours search. I do know how to use GIT, but I thought there might be a Laravel way to do it like many things seems to be done with artisan commands. If the update is only possible through GIT commands so have you found that you can do it without messing up the app folder where you have made your changes?
I have a quit new version of beta, only about one month old, but have worked on it already quit much.

Thanks for helping out one Laravel newb.

Answer (score 2):

If you have composer install globally run:

```
composer update
```

Otherwise (locally), run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Checkout [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/installation)